# CS50 'DNA': Ways to speed up my Week 6 'dna.py' program?

Tags: python, cs50

So for this problem I had to create a program that takes in two arguments. A CSV database like this:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

And a DNA sequence like this:

```
TAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
```

My program works by first getting the "Short Tandem Repeat" (STR) headers from the database (AGATC, etc.), then counting the highest number of times each STR repeats consecutively within the sequence. Finally, it compares these counted values to the values of each row in the database, printing out a name if a match is found, or "No match" otherwise.

The program works for sure, but is ridiculously slow whenever ran using the larger database provided, to the point where the terminal pauses for an entire minute before returning any output. And unfortunately this is causing the 'check50' marking system to time-out and return a negative result upon testing with this large database.

I'm presuming the slowdown is caused by the nested loops within the 'STR_count' function:

```
def STR_count(sequence, seq_len, STR_array, STR_array_len):
    # Creates a list to store max recurrence values for each STR
    STR_count_values = [0] * STR_array_len
    # Temp value to store current count of STR recurrence
    temp_value = 0

    # Iterates over each STR in STR_array
    for i in range(STR_array_len):
        STR_len = len(STR_array[i])

        # Iterates over each sequence element
        for j in range(seq_len):
            # Ensures it's still physically possible for STR to be present in sequence
            while (seq_len - j >= STR_len):
                # Gets sequence substring of length STR_len, starting from jth element
                sub = sequence[j:(j + (STR_len))]

                # Compares current substring to current STR
                if (sub == STR_array[i]):
                    temp_value += 1
                    j += STR_len
                else:
                    # Ensures current STR_count_value is highest
                    if (temp_value > STR_count_values[i]):
                        STR_count_values[i] = temp_value
                    # Resets temp_value to break count, and pushes j forward by 1
                    temp_value = 0
                    j += 1
        i += 1

    return STR_count_values
```

And the 'DNA_match' function:

```
# Searches database file for DNA matches
def DNA_match(STR_values, arg_database, STR_array_len):
    with open(arg_database, 'r') as csv_database:
        database = csv.reader(csv_database)

        name_array = [] * (STR_array_len + 1)
        next(database)

        # Iterates over one row of database at a time
        for row in database:
            name_array.clear()
            # Copies entire row into name_array list
            for column in row:
                name_array.append(column)

            # Converts name_array number strings to actual ints
            for i in range(STR_array_len):
                name_array[i + 1] = int(name_array[i + 1])

            # Checks if a row's STR values match the sequence's values, prints the row name if match is found
            match = 0
            for i in range(0, STR_array_len, + 1):
                if (name_array[i + 1] == STR_values[i]):
                    match += 1

                if (match == STR_array_len):
                    print(name_array[0])
                    exit()

        print("No match")
        exit()
```

However, I'm new to Python, and haven't really had to consider speed before, so I'm not sure how to improve upon this.

I'm not particularly looking for people to do my work for me, so I'm happy for any suggestions to be as vague as possible. And honestly, I'll value any feedback, including stylistic advice, as I can only imagine how disgusting this code looks to those more experienced.

[Here's a link to the full program](https://github.com/egyptianspacedog/tmpCS50helpneeded/blob/master/dna.py), if helpful.

Thanks :) x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing a link to the entire program. It seems needlessly complex, but I'd say it's just a lack of knowing what features are available to you. I think you've already identified the part of your code that's causing the slowness - I haven't profiled it or anything, but my first impulse would also be the three nested loops in `STR_count`.

Here's how I would write it, taking advantage of the Python standard library. Every entry in the database corresponds to one `person`, so that's what I'm calling them. `people` is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents one line in the database. We get this for free by using `csv.DictReader`.

To find the matches in the sequence, for every short tandem repeat in the database, we create a regex pattern (the current short tandem repeat, repeated one or more times). If there is a match in the sequence, the total number of repetitions is equal to the length of the match divided by the length of the current tandem repeat. For example, if `AGATCAGATCAGATC` is present in the sequence, and the current tandem repeat is `AGATC`, then the number of repetitions will be `len("AGATCAGATCAGATC") // len("AGATC")` which is `15 // 5`, which is `3`.

`count` is just a dictionary that maps short tandem repeats to their corresponding number of repetitions in the sequence. Finally, we search for a person whose short tandem repeat counts match those of `count` exactly, and print their name. If no such person exists, we print `"No match"`.

```
def main():

    import argparse
    from csv import DictReader
    import re

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("database_filename")
    parser.add_argument("sequence_filename")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.database_filename, "r") as file:
        reader = DictReader(file)
        short_tandem_repeats = reader.fieldnames[1:]
        people = list(reader)

    with open(args.sequence_filename, "r") as file:
        sequence = file.read().strip()

    count = dict(zip(short_tandem_repeats, [0] * len(short_tandem_repeats)))

    for short_tandem_repeat in short_tandem_repeats:
        pattern = f"({short_tandem_repeat}){{1,}}"
        match = re.search(pattern, sequence)
        if match is None:
            continue
        count[short_tandem_repeat] = len(match.group()) // len(short_tandem_repeat)

    try:
        person = next(person for person in people if all(int(person[k]) == count[k] for k in short_tandem_repeats))
        print(person["name"])
    except StopIteration:
        print("No match")
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```